# How do we obtain this inequality? A question concerning an argument in Stroock and Varadhan 1971

Tags: probability, proof-verification, stochastic-processes

The problem comes from the article of Stroock and Varadhan [diffusion processes with boundary conditions (1971) ]. [image]

So far I have followed, but in the next page I got lost:

[image]

I don't follow the first inequality, Since $J_u \phi = \langle \gamma(u,x(u)), \nabla \phi(x(u))\rangle$ one might try the following:
\begin{align*}
\int_{a'}^{b'} (\beta - \epsilon)\chi_U(x(u)) J_u \phi \, du 
&\leq \int_{a'}^{b'} \chi_U(x(u)) (\rho f_u + J_u f)(u,x(u))\,du \\
&\leq \int_{a'}^{b'} (\beta - \epsilon)\chi_U(x(u)) J_u \phi \, du
\end{align*}
And then use the result we are trying to prove:
\begin{align*}
\int_{a'}^{b'} (\beta - \epsilon)\chi_U(x(u)) \, d\xi_\phi(u) 
&\leq \int_{a'}^{b'} \chi_U(x(u)) \,d\xi_f(u) \\
&\leq \int_{a'}^{b'} (\beta - \epsilon)\chi_U(x(u))  \, d\xi_\phi(u)
\end{align*}
which finaly becomes
\begin{align*}
\int_{a'}^{b'} (\beta - \epsilon)\chi_U(x(u)) \, d\xi_\phi(u) 
&\leq \int_{a'}^{b'} \chi_U(x(u)) \alpha(u)\,d\xi_\phi(u) \\
&\leq \int_{a'}^{b'} (\beta - \epsilon)\chi_U(x(u))  \, d\xi_\phi(u)
\end{align*}

This however is wrong since I cannot use the result I am trying to prove, anyway, it may give some insight.

**Note:** I understand this question is not in the general knowledge. I tried to insert more images but (for good reasons I think) I wasn't able.

[image]

I will be glad to provide more details. Any hints are very welcome.